# Javascript return object value with properties

Tags: javascript, return-value, return-type

I am using Sharepoint 2013. i just wrote basic javascript code for our users get properties. it's not exactly what I can handle.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var date1 = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Kisiye Ozel Duyuru')/Items?$select=Title,ID,Duyuru_x0020_Atanan/Title,Duyuru_x0020_Aciklama&$expand=Duyuru_x0020_Atanan/Id";
           $.ajax({
              url: requestUri,
              type: "GET",
              headers: {
                  "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
              },
              success: onSuccess,
              error: onError
});


  function onSuccess(data) {
    if(data.d.results.length > 0){
        var objItems = data.d.results;
        var atanan = objItems[1].Duyuru_x0020_Atanan.Title;
        var baslik = objItems[1].Title;
        var aciklama = objItems[1].Duyuru_x0020_Aciklama;
        console.log(data.d.results);
        console.log(GetUserinfo());
        Bildirim(atanan,baslik,aciklama);
    }
   }
    function onError(error) {
        alert('Bildirimde bir hata var !');
   }
  });
  function Bildirim (atanan, baslik, aciklama){
  swal({
   title: '<strong>Sayın '+atanan+'</u></strong>',
  html:
    '<b>'+baslik+'</b>, ' +
    ''+aciklama+'' +
    '',
  imageUrl: 'http://intranet.uma.com.tr/SiteAssets/Duyuru.png',
  showCloseButton: false,
  showCancelButton: false,
  focusConfirm: false,
  confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up animated wow bounceInLeft"></i> Tamam!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Tamam!',
  cancelButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
  cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down',
});
  }
let GetUserinfo = function  () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
}

var context = null; 
var web = null; 
var currentUser = null;
var userGroups = null;
var displayGroups = null;

function getWebUserData() {

    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();   // Get the current user 
    web = context.get_web();                        // Get the current web    
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();            // Get the current user 
    context.load(currentUser);                      // Load the current user 

    context.executeQueryAsync(kaka, onFailureMethod);
}

let kaka = function () {

    /*/alert('User name:' + currentUser.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + currentUser.get_loginName());/*/
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(currentUser);
    var userTitle =currentUser.get_title();
    return userTitle;


}

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {

    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}


</script>
```

Here my code. i tried console.log(GetUserinfo) it return undefined. but i write 'alert(GetUserinfo())' in my kaka function its correctly work. I just need get value or property. Where am i wrong ?

Comment: `GetUserinfo` is async function that means it waits untill some script is loaded AND THEN executes the function. So instead `console.log(userInfo)` inside `getWebUserData()` function

Comment: or even better inside `kaka` function since `getWebUserData()` is also async function

Comment: this function should return a value i cant return value with my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my Solution, i am using SPservice.js Library and add properties my arraylist and return list;

```
 function UserProperties() {
        myGroups = new Array();
        var Name = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: ["Title"],
        debug: false
        });
        myGroups.push(Name);
        var Email = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: ["EMail"],
        debug: false
        });
        myGroups.push(Email);
        var Picture = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: ["Picture"],
        debug: false
        });
        myGroups.push(Picture);
        console.log(myGroups);
        return myGroups;
}
```